# Can I re-install a purchased app from Google's Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I've successfully purchased an app from the Market via my Android phone. It's currently too large for my internal memory (still running 2.1), so can I uninstall it and then re-install it at a later time?

Will uninstalling the app (after the 15 minute eval period elapses), also ensure that I can't re-download it again or do purchased apps remain linked to my Google account even if they aren't currently installed?

Comment: I thought the evaluation period was 24 hours.

Comment: Google changed it to 15 minutes in the latest market overhaul. I have no idea why 24 hrs was too long.  I think 15 minutes is excessively short.

Comment: So do most people, devs and users alike. The best compromise solution would be to allow the developer to choose a suitable time frame, IMHO

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can uninstall it and the market will remember that you bought it.  It'll say "purchased" in the market and you can reinstall any time. Every time I reflash a ROM I go into my downloads section of the market and I see all my purchased apps.

Comment: My friend and I tried it out, it was successful in the end. So if you do decide to delete it, I can assure you that it will comeback saying, "purchased".

Answer (score 9):

Procedure for most Android phones is: Open the "Market" application, click your phone's Menu button, click "Downloads" or "My Downloads", click name of App that you previously purchased, click Install button.

Note: If you've also changed the Google Account associated with the phone, then you'll lose the ability to install apps purchased under the old account.

Comment: Yes, good points.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to log in with the same Google Account when you bought the app. and you will be able to download/install it without paying again ...

Google store all app. / devices ... of each account

PS : Once on Google Play, go to My Application and you will find ever the purchased and non installed app. Or just look search for the app. and you will be able to download it without paying ...