# Can I download a paid app on a second device from Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

Say I have bought an app from Google Play and already have it installed on one device.

My question is – do I have to pay again if I download this app from Google Play from another device(but same Google account)?

Comment: Other related question [Can I re-install a purchased app from the Android market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4187/) and [Move paid apps between devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7099)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have your Google account on several devices and you'll be able to use all paid apps on all those devices. There is a device limit, however (around 10 I think) which is meant to prevent abuse of that.